# String matching between complete and incomplete(or short form) strings

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching

This question might get reported for duplicates, but I have done lots of research and haven't got anything satisfactory, so I thought its better I ask it precisely.

In my project, I need to match address strings. I have already implemented several string searching algorithms, like Soundex, Levenshtein distance, Damerau–Levenshtein distance,  Fuzzy Search, Character Frequency matching etc. But results become unsatisfactory for search between   strings like - St. and Street, Jr. and Junior etc. I thought of replacing all St. with Streets, but that will cause problems in addresses like 'St. Pauls Street'. 
What should I do?

Comment: Replace St. with Street only when in the end of the address.

Comment: Wont work, in cases like "Second St., Some Area", I have plenty of such addresses in the database. Thanks anyway but I need a more smart technique

Answer (score 1):

Create a string distance dictionary. Example: Distance('street','st')=0 . You need some training data to create this dictionary though.

Comment: Looks good, but doesn't there exist any algorithm or trick or something that might predict the long form or do matching. Your way seems best so far, but I think I should search for a more smarter method, since if I miss some short form than the search will be inconsistent. You still gave a last resort, thank you.

Comment: Smarter as in discovering "street" and "st" might be equivalent? That is almost impossible. But discovering such relations from data should be possible (depends on how smartly you can find such training data).